# Is there a difference between single thread and synchronous?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning Javascript with an online course. They say that the execution of Javascript is a "single threaded, synchronous execution". 
Then they define single thread as one command at a time and synchronous as one at a time. 
Is there a difference between these tho terms? 
Do we commonly say that Javascript is a synchronous language? Single threaded language?

Comment: Yes there is a difference. And JS is not a synchronous lang. There are async tasks like timers, ajax etc

Comment: @Rajesh Wrong. Answer

Comment: @SurajJain can you explain?

Comment: @Rajesh Sorry, Maybe you are right, I have to read much, someone who I know experienced programmer says javascript is syncronous in is behaviour. I am confused.

Comment: @SurajJain js is synchronous but it's has features to add async tasks as well. Point is most of the code will be executed in top down manner but for some functions, engine will not wait for the task to finish.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Single threaded means that only one thing happens at a time.

Synchronous means that if you need to wait for something, then everything stops until the wait is over.

The most common example of synchronous vs asynchronous in JavaScript is making an HTTP request.

If you make a synchronous request, then you send out the HTTP request over the network and then everything stops. Mouse clicks are ignored. Timers that reach zero at put on hold. Nothing happens until the response gets back.

If you want an asynchronous request, then the JS engine carries on with other work. When the request comes back, and the JS engine isn't busy, then it is picked up and dealt with.

Answer (score 11):

I found this and it really helped me to understand:

"In the end threading is about how many blocks of code (i.e. threads) we run on your computer's microprocessor simultaneously. If you have multiple 'cores' (like most modern Intel processors have) you can run multiple 'threads' simultaneously (i.e. each processor core is processing instructions at the same time). 
Javascript engines don't do this. Javascript doesn't necessarily get faster with more processor cores. 
On the other hand synchronous/asynchronous has to do with how a single thread is processed. Synchronous means 'wait for me to finish before doing something else'. Asynchronous means 'it's ok, keep going while I finish'.
Javascript is synchronous and single-threaded. Only one thing is happening at a time within the engine, and only one set of instructions is being sent to your computer's microprocessor."